# Grails UrlMappings with parameter values containing "."

Tags: grails, friendly-url, url-mapping

Given this UrlMapping:

```
"/foo/$foobar" {
    controller = "foo"
    action = "foo"
    constraints {
    }
}
```

Combined with this controller:

```
class FooController {
    def foo = {
        def foobar = params.foobar
        println "foobar=" + foobar
    }
}
```

And with these requests:

- http://localhost:8080/app/foo/example.com give the output "foobar=example"
- http://localhost:8080/app/foo/examplecom give the output "foobar=examplecom"

It seems like Grails cuts the "foobar" parameter at the first dot ("."). Is this intentional? Is there a work-around if I want to use parameters containing dots in my URL mappings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be solved by setting ...

```
grails.mime.file.extensions = false
```

... in Config.groovy.

It seems like Grails is trying to do some MIME magic behind the scene based on the file name suffix.

**Updated:** Some additional info from the [Grails JIRA](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-4253).

This is the offending code in UrlMappingsFilter.java:

```
    if(WebUtils.areFileExtensionsEnabled()) {
        String format = WebUtils.getFormatFromURI(uri);
        if(format!=null) {
            MimeType[] configuredMimes = MimeType.getConfiguredMimeTypes();
            // only remove the file extension if its one of the configured mimes in Config.groovy                                                                                                           
            for (MimeType configuredMime : configuredMimes) {
                if (configuredMime.getExtension().equals(format)) {
                    request.setAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.CONTENT_FORMAT, format);
                    uri = uri.substring(0, (uri.length() - format.length() - 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

WebUtils.areFileExtensionsEnabled() returns the value of the "grails.mime.file.extensions" setting configured in Config.groovy.